# Lunar sky brightness

Tags: the-moon, light

Looking at the report "The Measurements of Sky Brightness on Lunokhod-2"<sup>[1](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Edward-Terez-2/publication/248081808_The_measurements_of_sky_brightness_on_Lunokhod-2/links/53f6c6a30cf22be01c451795/The-measurements-of-sky-brightness-on-Lunokhod-2.pdf?origin=publication_detail)</sup>, I read that the day time visible light sky brightness was so large that it was off the scale. Unfortunately I have no idea how to convert their units of measurement into units I am familiar with, lux or lumens.

**Reference**

1. Severny, A. & Terez, Edward & Zvereva, A.. (**1975**). The measurements of sky brightness on Lunokhod-2. Earth Moon and Planets - EARTH MOON PLANET. 14. 123-128. 10.1007/BF00562978. ([pdf](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Edward-Terez-2/publication/248081808_The_measurements_of_sky_brightness_on_Lunokhod-2/links/53f6c6a30cf22be01c451795/The-measurements-of-sky-brightness-on-Lunokhod-2.pdf?origin=publication_detail))

Comment: Please add the relevant information also to this posting instead of only linking the paper

Comment: http://stjarnhimlen.se/comp/radfaq.html#7 may help, as may https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340230/

Comment: Thanks for the stjamhmlen link, very comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for ultraviolet light they give (table I), $4.68-25.8 ~\text{ergs/s}\times 10^5$, which would correspond to $80-260 ~\text{mW}$. As about a visual light, seems Lunokhod-2 telemetry systems was measuring sky brigntness in [S10](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1976LNP....48...41S/abstract) units,- relative light intensity to some "standard candle",- light captured from a main sequence star per 1 square degree solid angle. In these units Earth typical night sky has about $220~S_{10}$ [brightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_brightness). Lunokhod-2 claims giving brightness readings, even when within a shadow, of $4400~S_{10}$ units. That's about $20\times$ bigger brightness than at Earth night sky ! It may seem far too big value for a moon, but considering that moon has no light pollution, no atmosphere which would scatter Sun/stars light, and on average gray color of surface (which reflects light not bad, especially if you are in the highland calcium-rich region, which is brighter),- then it almost makes sense.